# Видеокарта в Linux

Tags: linux

Стояла винда. Была частота обновления экрана 120 Гц. Поставил Убунту - тут мне предлагают только 60 Гц. Почему так?

Comment: Что за карта, какой драйвер?

Comment: радеоновская старая.

Comment: Драйвер проприетарный?

Comment: Я не знаю. Просто надо узнать какая видюха и каккой драйвер надо ей и поставить его

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 sudo su

    gtf

    gtf 1680 1050 60

1680 это X - разрешение по горизонтали,  1050 - это Y - разрешение по вертикали,      60 частота обновления
```

ввести нужные параметры
Далее - проверяем  наличие /etc/X11/xorg.conf типа

```
ls /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

если его нет.
действие 2

```
nano /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

действие 3 - копируем и вставляем туда строки :

```
# xorg.conf (X.Org X Window System server configuration file)
#
# This file was generated by dexconf, the Debian X Configuration tool, using
# values from the debconf database.
#
# Edit this file with caution, and see the xorg.conf manual page.
# (Type "man xorg.conf" at the shell prompt.)
#
# This file is automatically updated on xserver-xorg package upgrades *only*
# if it has not been modified since the last upgrade of the xserver-xorg
# package.
#
# Note that some configuration settings that could be done previously
# in this file, now are automatically configured by the server and settings
# here are ignored.
#
# If you have edited this file but would like it to be automatically updated
# again, run the following command:
#   sudo dpkg-reconfigure -phigh xserver-xorg

Section "Device"
Identifier   "Configured Video Device"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
Identifier   "Configured Monitor"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
Identifier   "Default Screen"
Monitor      "Configured Monitor"
Device      "Configured Video Device"
EndSection
```

действие 4 -  F2 (сохранить)
действие 5 - копируем параметры (сами смотрите, что вам соответствует)

```
gtf 1920 1200 60 >> /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

действие 7

```
nano /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

должно быть в конце файла

```
# 1920x1200 @ 60.00 Hz (GTF) hsync: 74.52 kHz; pclk: 193.16 MHz
Modeline "1920x1200_60.00"  193.16  1920 2048 2256 2592  1200 1201 1204 1242  -HSync +Vsync
```

переносим их в секцию Section "Monitor" , что бы получилось что-то вроде :

```
Section "Monitor"
Identifier   "Configured Monitor"
# 1920x1200 @ 60.00 Hz (GTF) hsync: 74.52 kHz; pclk: 193.16 MHz
Modeline "1920x1200_60.00"  193.16  1920 2048 2256 2592  1200 1201 1204 1242  -HSync +Vsync
EndSection
```

действие 8 - сохранить, и перегрузиться 
действие 9 - проверить сохранение параметров монитора(Система -> Параметры -> Монитор), то что указали.
действие 10 - выбрать ваши параметры!
действие 11 - наслаждаться монитором :)

Comment: russia-desktop russia # gtf 1920 1080 120

  # 1920x1080 @ 120.00 Hz (GTF) hsync: 138.84 kHz; pclk: 368.76 MHz
  Modeline "1920x1080_120.00"  368.76  1920 2072 2288 2656  1080 1081 1084 1157  -HSync +Vsync


Изменения приняты или нет?
Просто когда захожу в параметры то все остается по прежнему